# SQL: unique constraint and aggregate function

Tags: sql, database

Presently I'm learning (MS) SQL, and was trying out various aggregate function samples. The question  I have is: Is there any scenario (sample query that uses aggregate function) where having a unique constraint column (on a table) helps when using an aggregate function.

Please note: I'm not trying to find a solution to a problem, but trying to see if such a scenario exist in real world SQL programming.

Comment: Perhaps you should define "helps". Your question is vague as of now

Answer (score 1):

One immediate theoretical scenario comes to mind, the unique constraint is going to be backed by a unique index, so if you were just aggregating that field, the index would be narrower than scanning the table, but that would be on the basis that the query didn't use any other fields and was thus covering, otherwise it would tip out of the NC index.

I think the addition of the index to enforce the unique constraint is automatically going to have the ability to potentially help a query, but it might be a bit contrived.

Put the unique constraint on the field if you need the field to be unique, if you need some indexes to help query performance, consider them seperately, or add a unique index on that field + include other fields to make it covering (less useful, but more useful than the unique index on a single field)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take following two tables, one has records for subject name and subject Id and another table contains record for student having marks in particular subjects.

> Table1(SubjectId int unique, subject_name varchar, MaxMarks int) 
>   Table2(Id int, StudentId int, SubjectId, Marks int)

so If I need to find AVG of marks obtained in Science subject by all student who have attempted for 
Science(SubjectId =2) then I would fire following query.

```
SELECT AVG(Marks),  MaxMarks  
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE Table1.SubjectId = 2;
```

Comment: Ansi joins at least please - no join condition and the where clause doesn't cover table 2, so it will cartesian table1 / table 2 then filter down to table1.subjectid=2, but the average would be over every table 2 record due to the cartesian.

Comment: If you want to make this query more generic then join will help  as you only need to change WHERE clause by Table1.SubjectId = Table2.SubjectId

AND you can also take Subject_Name field along with rest.

Comment: Three issues : The query does not do what you are saying it does.  You do not specify how a unique constraint is going to help the query. There are no real excuses to not use ansi-joins.

Comment: Above query is written in MySQL and yes it's giving result to me in same.

Comment: This is a SQL SERVER question - MS SQL is specified by the poster, MY SQL is not an answer.

Comment: He also said "if such a scenario exist in real world SQL programming."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19236/discussion-between-andrew-and-vardan-gupta)